# Meaning of 無難に行く

Tags: translation, meaning, adverbs

Context: the author is telling she cut her hair in a way she didn't like before an important event. Then she says this:

> 思い出に残る写真をいっぱい撮るんだから本当なら無難に行きたい所... それなのに何故！！

I know 無難に means `safely`/`without fault`/`innocuously`, but does it have a particular meaning when used with 行く?

My (bad) attempt: "Since I take a lot of unforgettable pictures, if that is true I want to go safely (?)... Why did this happen?!"

Source: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZ4L5.jpg (the letter on the left, near the end)

Comment: Im guessing it says like to "proceed carefully" like kind of a "just in case" sense of tone... idk your attempt is reasonable though. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

無難に行く and 無難にやる are set phrases that mean "to play it safe", "to take the safe path" etc. Let's memorize them as is. In this case, it just says she wanted an ordinary hair style. (I don't know why she hates [前髪ぱっつん](https://www.rankingshare.jp/rank/ipuhzyclwm) that strongly, though)

BTW this [本当なら](http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E6%9C%AC%E5%BD%93%E3%81%AA%E3%82%89) means 本来なら/本来は ("under normal circumstances", "usually").

Comment: Thank you! So the translation would be something like "Since I take a lot of unforgettable pictures, I usually would go for an ordinary cut", right? I'm not convinced about 'unforgettable' though...

Comment: @Marco Looks good to me. 'Unforgettable' is not wrong but may be a bit too strong. How about 'memorable'?